Taboo on Sexuality
Another question on that topic was closed due to "pushing a personal philosophy", though I almost expected it to be closed due to being a duplicate and I'm kinda amazed that no one asked the question before (or maybe I'm just not able to find it).
So: Is there research into why sexuality is a taboo? Or relatedly whether it started as a taboo or became one?

Like there certainly is some sort of taboo around sexuality (at least in western culture, not sure that is a universal thing). And if I think about it I could come up with lots of possible reasons for why that could be the case, idk being naked and engaged makes you an easy prey (so animals usually do it quick while extended activities could be dangerous), "the creation of life" has some spiritual quality to it and the ability to do that privately could challenge religious narratives, maybe the pre-mating process got excessive (like watching documentaries one might get the impression that doing outstanding things and brutal violence are common to impress a partner, yet might be a limiting factor for larger societies), maybe envy causes problems, maybe intimacy is risky beyond external predators, maybe it's about children (either because it seals the fate of a women to become mother or because offspring is needed for dynasties, catholic celibacy  for priests is apparently to avoid them passing on the fortune of the church and the rest is fitted retroactively, ...), maybe it's about STDs and the fact that it's raw, gooey, smelly and whatnot, which is gross when you think about it, but not when you do it, so fantasy doing it's thing, maybe it's primal and thus seen as "primitive" detraction from more "important" things, another more sinister angle might be shaming of rape victims so that they can't talk about the crime and thus not confront the criminals or in general using shame as a weapon against people (a crime that you can't avoid gives justification for unjustified punishment) or maybe it stems from growing into it, so childhood perceptions are continued into adulthood and passed on to children again(???) and so on and on and on. Despite being long this list is likely by far not conclusive.
In some of those cases the taboo is deliberate in others the taboo follows from something being private and people speculating why it should be private. Also in some cases the taboo might have had a purpose, but is now obsolete, in other cases it might have never actually worked to begin with, in yet other cases there might still be a benefit (or maybe an unethical one)? Though there are 2 elephants in the room here: For one there's rarely any conclusive answer already given within society, so either it is a mix of anything and everything or these "reasons" are more retrofitted to an existing situation, rather than being explanations for causing it and the other is that despite being in some way shape or form a taboo, it's almost impossible not to be violated without the species going extinct so there is an inherent contradiction in it.
So is there serious research into the social taboo around sex and why it's there or why it's still there?

You can start from Freud's Totem and Tabooo (original 1913)

Being civilized and not falling prey to our animalistic desires, whether it’s sex on the more harmless side of things, or murder on the more harmful, is part of what caused society to flourish. If sex wasn’t taboo, people especially back in the day would have been more motivated to rape, relationships would be more likely to break down given the higher willingness to cheat, etc. It’s a social phenomenon designed to keep people in check

Historically, sex was dangerous. Obviously, there are STD problems, but that's not the most dangerous part: pregnancy is. If you have an unwanted pregnancy, you have a resource drain that is potentially life-threatening for the mother.

Did you try to find research about it? There are whole libraries full of both speculative/critical and historical, empirical, anthropological, social, psychological, cross-cultural research about this topic. The reason why the earlier questions may have been closed was probably that -- like here -- no clear motivation is given for the philosophical relevance of the question (which itself is posed as an overly general question). To be sure, I do believe that such motivations can be given, but it's unclear to me what yours is.

@mudskipper Then would you mind linking to those libraries or summarize their findings or the state of the art of that research? Also that snippet about the closed question is really really short, how did you manage to misread that ... entirely?

@MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks for the reference almost forgot about Freud, though how much of his research stood the test of time, wasn't he accused of pseudoscience later on? Anyway thanks for the reference!

@Syed That sounds highly speculative. Also as said you can also speculate the opposite of that, in that the taboo aides to cover up and thus enables rape. So are there sources more elaborating your claims?

@haxor789 - As to Totem and Taboo not having "stood the test of time" - that's probably true. See for instance Lévi-Strauss criticism of Freud. But it's still a seminal study, so important at the very least in order to understand later studies. (And imo it's always better to read original studies rather than commentaries + summaries which invariably bring in their own bagage of biases.)

See the references in this answer on a related question

This seems to be more a question of history of sociology/psychology than philosophy.

You are really asking a sociology or anthropology question here, although philosophers like Foucault and Lacan have very much engaged with this domain.
Humans are very rare in preferring sex in private, only one other species has been found like that, and it's a bat not one of the social apes or monkeys. We can relate the 'hijacking' of shame and disgust, to the grounding of the emergence of culture, specifically in the development of their application toward enabling pro-social behaviours. See discussion here: How do ethicists tackle the question "Is it immoral to have sex in public places?" Is it possible to use rational and empirical ideas to answer?
Hume's Is-Ought distinction shows us, that the deeper values and impulses that guide us, like what we feel shame and disgust about, are not determined by reasoning from what is, but come from internal felt impulses.

"Reason is, and ought only to be the slave of the passions, and can
never pretend to any other office than to serve and obey them."
-David Hume in A Treatise of Human Nature

Jonathan Haidt did work on 'moral dumbfounding', where our intuitions about why we react to certain situations are challenged, eg there is no harm involved. See discussion here: Why do we prohibit consensual incestuous relationships?
Haidt developed Moral Foundations theory, from research that identified core cross-cultural drivers of pro-social behaviours, eg a desire for fairness, which is also found in other social animals.
It's reasonable to think these 'foundations' have been biologically selected for their social benefits. Although this is challenged by a low but persistent rate of psychopathy.
Having sex in private seems to help humans cooperate, especially between genders and between compeitors for reproductive opportunities. AO Wilson identifies regulating reproduction as a group, as a key trait in 'eusociality', the suite of behaviours he relates to hive-like behaviours and the group-selection dynamics within a context of multi-level selection (this distinction is important because groups cannot take primacy as units of selection over genes). Humans seem to have had a phase of regulating reproduction, probably when food was more scarce (the stability of human population sizes over long periods suggests food-scarcity limited fertility through most of human history). Culture seems to have emerged as more pursuasion rather than coercion in this domain, and we can understand taboos as happening at close to the same instinctive level as sexual behaviour and reproductive drive, but as directed by cultural mechanisms like sharing causes of shame and disgust socially. A good example is behaviour around 'naming and shaming' cuckolds, who if they haven't personally acted to stop the behaviour for whatever reason, are forced to do so by community response. We can link such enforcement of social roles to the maintenance of unstable game-theory equilibria, whereby individuals forego some good like combining with better genes for a social benefit like securing care for offspring.
Durkheim created the term sacred contagion, related to ritual purity or ritual cleanliness. Here we can see how intuitions about disgust get channeled by cultural or religious mechanisms. The Romini marime laws that originated in Persian Parsi culture, or Jewish dietary laws, are good examples of this process of channeling direct feelings and responses into larger cultural structures, which also come to support group identity and cohesion. Durkheim's larger picture of society comes from his analysis of religion, that it derives from 'enactment of shared attitudes to sacred things'. This is a clever turn of phrase, that can help us make sense of the huge array of past religious behaviours, and also of modern superficially 'post religious' societies in the same terms.
We have outpourings of social response to particular events, the #MeToo movement, or the murder of Sarah Everard by a policeman, or the response to the murder of babies by nurse Lucy Letby. We can link these to Dukheim's 'collective effervescence', experiences of being in community together, that he linked with breaking from the 'profane' mundane life, and connecting with sacred values held by the group and relating to less personal and time-bound themes. Note these events involve the encounter between past or intergenerational collections of knowledge, and the modern community experiencing itself. And if society changes very quickly, there is a danger not only of traditions being too outdated to draw on, but of social decohesion, eg because of a lack of trust that others are investing in the social order eneough to keep forgoing personal advantage that would damage our ability to cooperate.
The circle to be squared, is that social mores are not fixed, culture is not fixed, even biology changes. So we must recognise that taboos and morality don't exist in a vacuum, they do not belong to Plato's realm of ideal forms. They are time-bound, and reacting to social conditions and dynamics, though by reaching for lessons that are meaningful for more than one generation we can see how we seek to 'universalise', as evidenced by the developments in religious thinking from demigods defining their own morality, to tribal customs that can't be broken even by kings, to 'universal citizenship' as all humans are accepted as 'within the humsn tribe' as moral subjects, and potentially onwards as identified by Peter Singer as the 'expanding circle of moral concern' taking up animals as moral subjects.
I would identify intersubjectivity as crucial to why this dynamic is happening, increasing our intersubjectivity or expanding our personal experiences by taking the experiences of other minds as being like our own, enables more cooperation (eg learning to work with dogs likely gave homo sapiens an edge over other hominids). Discussed more here: Is the Categorical Imperative Simply Bad Math? :) and here Studies exploring the rationale of gender equality

By simply searching the web or asking a current LLM you can find lots of research that is relevant to the question why there are social, cultural, or perhaps even biological taboos (plural) around various aspects (plural) of sexuality. You can even find speculative discourse that discusses philosophical aspects of this -- from all kinds of angles, either in terms of marxist, freudian, structuralist or feminist ideology critique or in terms of etiology of moral concepts (or even more general than just moral concepts).
I'll just give a random sample of links that mixes up historical, empirical research with speculative criticism of ideology:

Sigmund Freud, Totem and Taboo
Michel Foucault, The History of Sexuality
Adrienne Rich, Compulsory Heterosexuality and Lesbian Existence
Frans De Waal, Primates and Philosophers: How morality evolved
Frans De Waal, Bonobo: The Forgotten Ape

If you look in the index and literature list of Foucault or De Waal no doubt you'll find a lifetime worth of readings.
As Confucius said

I have sometimes, trying to think something through for myself, spent a whole day without eating and a whole night without sleep. But to no avail. It's better to study. (Lunyü 15:31)


I think the problem is what I call "context fault."
No matter how sophisticated we are, sex and death force us to remember that we're really just intelligent animals created only to mate and die.
For the same reason, I used to be really embarrassed if I was in a car with people and we drove past a cemetery.
The taboo allows us to pretend that we're something more... until we go home to our husbands and wives.

But we are something more, even if innately we are animals. If we weren’t, society wouldn’t have flourished. We have the cognitive capacity to control for our sexual desires the same way we control our desire for aggression and wanting to kill everyone off. A society that tolerated sex in any circumstance would be more tolerant to rape. A society that tolerated violence in any circumstance would be more tolerant to murder. A society that tolerated motives to attain power in any circumstance would result in more authoritarian countries. Etc


But we are something more, === Sure. You can do a lot of things with wood. But that's only 1 reason wood was created, and that's to make more wood.


"We" are riding around in a weirdly adapted chimpanzee which has its own responses and priorities. Usually it is fairly well trained and does the tricks we have taught it on command, but that doesn't mean it's instincts aren't pulling it in other directions.  "We" are the something more, but the ape is still the ape. (I've become very aware of this as I age and the ape has started pushing back on some of the training if I don't pay attention.)

Be careful, @keshlam, Don't separate the two halves of who you are. I've studied a lot of incels when I had my blog, and that's how they happen. You must integrate the 2. see Star Trek episode, The Enemy Within.

@Miss_Understands: I don't think anyone actually understands them, outside of trying to blame everyone else for their frustration. I know nobody understands me, and that's okay. Usually the ape and the cat agree; when they don't they work it out peaceably. I am as well integrated as anyone, I just understand what is being integrated.

@keshlam > I don't think anyone actually understands them === I do. I spent three years in a cave with a blog devoted to understanding them. This was an ad. when one of them stalked me, I ended the blog (by orders of the people I live with). I decribed it again last week on the space exploration stax meta.

I accept that you think you do. It's unrelated to the topic currently at hand, so I will let it rest there.

Ah! Love n Death. The perennial core of poetry.  Perhaps youre pointing to something stronger : Some subjects just cant be addressed in a ratiocinative framing but need oblique approaches like poetry, humor etc

@Keshlam s 2 half's reminds me of an allegory from Gurdjieff: You have in you a wolf and a sheep.  It is your duty to preserve and nurture these disparate types of beings

You may have felt embarrassed by a cemetary. I don't think that's a normal response. Burial is a truly ancient practice, going back almost to the beginning of hominids, & seems to relate to feelings about bodily sanctity even in death, & not wanting to see the body consumed by animals. We feel at least a little in the presence of the dead in a cemetary, though how people respond to that varies (eg Dia Del Meurte, Polish cemetary picnics on All Saints Day)

On 'created only to mate and die', see 'Is the pleasure of drugs better than long term achievements?' for Denis Noble's explicit counterpoint to the 'gene machines' view of Dawkins, https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/99821/is-the-pleasure-of-drugs-better-than-long-term-achievements/99841#99841

@CriglCragl Hey, don' you BE disrespectin' Dawkins, now, y'hear! === [puts on matrix shades] What would you say if I told you that someone can believe intelligent design AND yet be an original and present disciple of Dawkins? === YUP! [curtsies] === Following your link now. Charge that lightsaber. [Gee, I wonder if this one's religious, or an evolutionary bio, or...] Well, it doesn't matter. What does matter is the truth. To the extent that truth matters, it makes an impenetrable shield and a devastating weapon. Problem is forcing  a context where truth matters. Not on THIS  Planet of the Apes

@CriglCragl 'Is drugs better than achievements? == YES! I lay around high all day, 24/7 after winning awards for nuclear engineering by people who applauded me through gritted teeth. Am I wasting my superpower? I don't care! I'm the X-Man who said, "fuck it" and hangs out in Xavier's School for Extraordinary Children. And speaking of children, I never had any. I'm like a teenager. In my job, that makes me priceless to men. And it allows me to lay around and smoke drugs all day instead of programming surface integrals. In the meantime, I shoot X-Man flame from my fingertips to light my joint.

@Miss_Understands: You may find these answers relevent to that in terms of the 'examined life': 'Meaning of life, given all my problems have been solved' https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/24145/meaning-of-life-given-all-my-problems-have-been-solved/94489#94489 And 'Does anybody understand what Nietzsche meant by ‘Seriousness in Play’?' https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/112275/does-anybody-understand-what-nietzsche-meant-by-seriousness-in-play/112282#112282

Does anybody understand what he meant by "conquering the Spirit of Gravity?" No one but children, Feynman, and me. That's why Nietzsche's final form was a child.

Okay, @Miss_Understands can be counted on for overblown rhetoric. I now know how much weight to give to those comments; thank you.

@keshlam criglcragl asked me about a relevant, particularly deep statement by an 1870 philosopher whom you've never heard of. I replied with another one. Yes, If you would like to ignore the conversation, that probably would be best.

It doesn't pay to overthink these things…

Humans are social (group-dependent) creatures
Sexuality is a desirable resource
Competition over desirable resources produces in-group conflict
In-group conflict needs to be controlled and limited for the survival of the group
Sexual institutions and taboos control and limit in-group conflict

Spend a few days in your average high school and observe all the drama and trauma that hinges on sexuality and relationships: hurt feelings, social jockeying, bullying, desperations, frustrations, etc., all resulting from controlled but emotionally intense competition. Now imagine that same high school without sexual taboos or institutions to worry about. Not pretty…

Apart from sounding sexist and objectifying to claim sexuality as resource, it also sounds wrong. Like what about it is a resource? Procreating? Sure there's at least a 9 month cooldown and afterwards you've got a lot more to mind about. But that's not the kind of sexuality that your high schoolers care about, which has a much shorter cooldown or could even be DIY... So in that sense the taboo would create the scarcity and thus the problem to begin with.

@haxor789: Don't impose judgements, please. I didn't say it was a resource for any particular group or person. (Almost) everyone wants sex, regardless of gender, race, post-pubescent age, religion, socioeconomic status, etc. Sex is desirable because it's pleasurable; sex is desirable because it produces children; sex is desirable because it's an expression of trust and love; any or all of those can come into play in any given instance. You think it sounds sexist because you're caught in a masculinist perspective, but women can (and often do) objectify men when it comes to sex.

@haxor789: Further, sex falls into that category of 'status' resources where the Veblen effect comes into play: interest increases as the desired outcome is perceived as less accessible (the social analog of more costly). Sexual partners are often viewed as a measure of social standing (the cheerleader who wants to impress others by dating a football star; the frat boy who wants notches on his belt; the socialites looking for a 'good match' to secure their status; the regular people who want to have families to show their good lives…)

@haxor789: You underestimate high-schoolers, who may be hormonal but still have complex wants and needs. And you underestimate the power and pervasiveness of this resource.
